# How to get an object index from an array in swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I am creating a class in swift work as a container of a set of protocols. Below is the source code. The `KeyValueObserverDelegate` protocol is added in `KeyValueObserverService` class by `addObserver()` method. The problem happens on `removeObserver()` method, the line is `index = array.indexOf($0 == observer)`.

I got an error:

> anonymous closure argument not contained in a closure.

I don't know what wrong with my class. How can I get the index of an object from an array?

```
class KeyValueObserverService{

    private var observerList:Dictionary<String, [KeyValueObserverDelegate]> = Dictionary()

    func addObserver(key:String, observer:KeyValueObserverDelegate){
        var array:Array<KeyValueObserverDelegate>?
        if observerList.keys.contains(key){
            array = observerList[key]
        } else {
            array = Array<KeyValueObserverDelegate>()
            self.observerList[key] = array
        }
        array?.append(observer)
    }

    func updateValueForKey(key:String, value:AnyObject?){
        let array = self.observerList[key];
        if array == nil{
            return
        }
        for  element in array!{
            element.valueChanged(value)
        }
    }

    func removeObserver(key:String, observer:KeyValueObserverDelegate){
        if self.observerList.keys.contains(key) == false{
            return
        }
        var array:[KeyValueObserverDelegate] = self.observerList[key]!;

        let index:Int?


        index = array.indexOf($0 == observer)

        array.removeAtIndex(index!)
    }
}

protocol KeyValueObserverDelegate :class{
    func valueChanged(value:AnyObject?)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the error message carefully

> ...not contained in a closure

By definition a closure is enclosed in a pair of curly braces

```
array.indexOf({$0 == observer})
```

or with trailing closure syntax

```
array.indexOf{$0 == observer}
```

**Edit:**

Since a protocol does not conform to `Equatable` by default use the *identity operator*

```
array.indexOf{$0 === observer}
```

Comment: Thanks for correcting me. After make this change, the error message becomes "Binary operator "==" cannot be applied to "KeyValueObserverDelegate" operands.

Comment: `KeyValueObserverDelegate` seems to be a custom type. You need to make the type conform to the `Equatable` protocol by implementing the `==` operator.

Comment: KeyValueObserverDelegate is defined as a protocol, it is located at the bottom of my post. How can I conform to Equatable?

Comment: KeyValueObserverDelegate is defined as a protocol, it is located at the bottom of my post. When I add Equable, my code will report a lot errors. Most of them are "KeyValueObserverDelegate  can only be used as a generic constraint"

Comment: Either use the identity operator (`===`) or add an `identifier` property or something else unique to the protocol to be able to identify the particular observer. I edited the answer.